# Typescript/Angular - Create array of objects from json file then get specific item

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having difficulty trying to accomplish a task.
I have a json file like this:

```
[
{
    "name" : "blah",
    "size" : "medium",
    "speed" : 25,
},
{
    "name" : "blah",
    "subtype" : ["blah", "blah", "blah"],
    "size" : "medium",
    "speed" : 30,
},
{
    "name" : "blah",
    "size" : "medium",
    "speed" : 30,
}
```

]

I want to create an array of objects, which I believe I have to do like this:

```
getObjects() {
  return this.http.get('/assets/raceInfo.json');
}
```

Then I would like to get a specific one something like:

```
getObject(name: string) {
  return this.http.get('/assets/raceInfo.json').select(x => x.name === name);
}
```

i'm completely new to typescript and angular, so any help much appreciated.

Comment: Typically, your backend API will have an endpoint that allows you to fetch a specific instance of an entity. If you don't have access to such an endpoint, you'll probably want to use the `filter `method of `array`.

Comment: And, in Angular **this.http.get(...)** return an observable of type HttpResponse. So to get your data and work on it, your have to subscribe. See the documentation : https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response